# Thunderbolt monitor running at 30Hz when second monitor connected

Tags: display, thunderbolt, hdmi, 4k

I have a MacBook Pro (15 inch, 2018, Radeon Pro 560X) to which I plug 2 external monitors: a LG 32UL950 4K over thunderbolt & an old ASUS full HD over HDMI.
The problem is when the ASUS is connected then the LG is only running at 30Hz.
[image]

When connected alone it's fine at 60Hz.
[image]

This machine is supposed to support *4* 4K@60Hz screens. Any idea how to fix this?
(I can't confirm it but I think this issue started with one of the latest macOS updates, 11.3 or 11.4)

EDIT: Display preferences
[image]

Comment: One thing that looks a little odd to me is that in the top screenshot (with the Asus connected), the resolution of the LG is 8K rather than 4K. When the Asus is connected are you able to force the LG to 60Hz via *System Preferences* > *Displays*?

Comment: Yes indeed the 8K resolution doesn't make any sense. There is no refresh rate option available for the LG in the display preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check out the RDM app http://avi.alkalay.net/software/RDM/? You should be able to manually set your refresh rate. This may fix issues. It may be driving at 8K @ 30 because running at 8K @ 60 = 4x 4K @ 60. When you have another display, it (incorrectly) realizes it doesn't have enough power and switches to 30 fps. Remember that the mac may be rendering at a higher resolution (8k) and scaling it up (like how the 5k imacs work). This could be wasting gpu power because of the incorrect resolution data (should be 4k, not 8k). RDM may help fix this by giving the actual resolution and FPS being used.